How to ensure the negative sign exports correctly in stat_cor element in a ggplot graph?
I am exporting editable ggplots to powerpoint slides. Each graph has a correlation. When the correlation R value is negative, this exports as a box in the graph, instead of a negative sign in text.
An example of the resulting issue is shown as an image and an example of my code is below. Thanks for any insight!

Below is the code I've been using to generate the graphs:
 # generate plot
 p< - data %>%
 ggplot(aes_string(x = "x_value", y = "y_value")) +
 geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~x, se=TRUE, color="black") + 
 geom_point(aes(shape=group, fill= group), size=4) +
 labs(title = paste("Title"), 
   y = "Y title", 
   x= "X title" ) +
 scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 10, 1), limits=c(0, 10)) +
 scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 400, 25), limits=c(0, 400))+
 theme_bw() +
 theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 20),
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.title = element_text(face="bold", size=24),
    axis.text = element_text(size=24)
  )  +
 stat_cor(label.y.npc="top", label.x.npc = "left",
       size=7,
       method="pearson")


 # creating a new slide and inserting the plot 
 graphs <- add_slide(graphs, layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") 
 graphs <- ph_with(graphs, dml(ggobj = p), location = ph_location_fullsize()) 


Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

I was able to resolve this by specifying output.type="text" to the stat_cor command. This successfully exported the negative sign as a text box, instead of an object that did not display in powerpoint.
Code below:
   stat_cor(label.y.npc="top", label.x.npc = "left",
   size=7,
   method="pearson",  output.type = "text")


Maybe it's a font face thing on your powerpoint. If you highlight the box and change to a different font, hopefully the negative sign may appear.
I tried a version of your code (see bottom) and ended up with a negative sign that wasn't centered and could be manually moved up on the output when viewed on LibreOffice (I don't have powerpoint). I hope this helps.


# generate plot
p <- iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~x, se=TRUE, color="black") + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=Species, fill= Species), size=4) +
  labs(title = paste("Plot"), 
       y = "Y title", 
       x= "X title" ) +
  #scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 10, 1), limits=c(0, 10)) +
  #scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 400, 25), limits=c(0, 400))+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 20),
        legend.position = "none",
        axis.title = element_text(face="bold", size=24),
        axis.text = element_text(size=24)
  )  +
  ggpubr::stat_cor(label.y.npc="top", label.x.npc = "left",
           size=7,
           method="pearson")

p
# creating a new slide and inserting the plot 
graphs <- read_pptx()
graphs <- officer::add_slide(graphs, layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") 
graphs <- officer::ph_with(graphs, rvg::dml(ggobj = p), location = ph_location_fullsize())
base::print(graphs, target = here::here(
  "graphs.pptx"))

